# Php search in database to show data, not working

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to display some data from my database, and i dosen't work when i try to display some of the data, specified by a search bar. Here is the code. I hope someone can fix my problem.

Ive tried for a few hours, but nothing seems to work.

I removed most of the html code, to even be able to post.

```html
<?php
 include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for graphicscard"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />

<?php



?>

    </form>

    <table width="600" border="1" cellpaddin="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>


<th>Graphicscard</th>
<th>Coin</th>
<th>Hashrate</th>
<th>Bios-modded</th>
<th>Core-clock</th>
<th>Memory-clock</th>
<th>Power draw</th>
<th>Additional info</th>
        </tr>

      <?
  if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace("#[^`0-9a-z]#i","", $searchq);
    
        $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM 'cards' WHERE 'name' LIKE '$search%' OR coin LIKE '$search%'") or die ("No results");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($queryQ);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['coin'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['hashrate'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['bios_mod'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['core_clock'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['memory_clock'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['power_draw'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['additional_info'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: how doesn't it work? Are you getting an error message, is it outputting something but not everything? Also you need to wrap your <tr><td></td></tr> in `<table>`

Comment: It dosent show an error message, it just shows nothing

Comment: In your query youre using variable `$search` but you don't have variable with that name.

Answer (score 0):

The mysqli_query() used as a function needs the link id returned by mysqli_connect() o mysqli_init()

[PHP mysqli_query() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

So you need a $connection var:

```
 $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

and the use it on the query:

```
 mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM 'cards' WHERE 'name' LIKE '$search%' OR coin LIKE '$search%'") or die ("No results");
```

Comment: I already have the connection thing, in another file, and then i just include it, at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$search` in the query, but the correct variable should be `$searchq` .

Answer (score 0):

Do you get correct query result and how many rows in it? As I can see were is a mistake in your query:

SELECT * FROM 'cards' WHERE 'name' LIKE...

Name of table and fields should be in another quoats - `

SELECT * FROM `cards` WHERE `name` LIKE...

Or this is typing issue on posted message?

On this row: $count = mysqli_num_rows(**$queryQ**); - you variable of query result is - $query not $queryQ

Comment: I have changed it to SELECT * FROM 'cards' WHERE 'name' LIKE. And here is the the textbox which it's supposed to get the search data from.     <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for graphicscard"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an alternative way:**

```
select * from cards where name like 'ABC%'
union
select * from cards where coin like 'XYZ%'
union
select * from cards where gender like 'PQR%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code on this:

```
  if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^`0-9a-z]#i","", $searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cards WHERE name LIKE '$searchq%' OR coin LIKE '$searchq%'") or die ("No results");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['coin'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['hashrate'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['bios_mod'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['core_clock'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['memory_clock'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['power_draw'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['additional_info'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
```

If you use mysqli please see this [referenc](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) on how to use it

in your tag form add method of sending data POST: <form method="POST">